# Determine if this specific sequence is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

I have the following sequence:
$$a_n =\sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{b_k} {1\over k^2}  $$
And the hint is that I have to prove that:
$$ {1\over k^2}  < {1\over k-1} - {1\over k}  $$

So assuming $m>n$, I have to prove that:
$$\forall \epsilon >0,  \exists N \in \mathbb{N},$$ so that $$  \forall m,n > N \Rightarrow \lvert a_m - a_n\rvert < \epsilon $$

What I gathered so far:
$ \lvert a_m - a_n\rvert = \lvert \sum_{k = n+1}^m (-1)^{b_k} {1\over k^2}\rvert $

$b_k$ is a sequence of natural numbers ${1,2,3.....}$, so in absolute value, $(-1)^{b_k} $ is $1$.
Therefore:

$ \lvert a_m - a_n\rvert = \lvert \sum_{k = n+1}^m (-1)^{b_k} {1\over k^2}\rvert \leq \sum_{k = n+1}^m {1\over k^2}. $

From here on, its not so clear to me as to how to proceed.
What should be my next steps?

Comment: Note that (as suggested in one of the edits) the last equality in the last line should be an inequality $\leq$.

Comment: Just saw it, fixed, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost done. Since $\frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$ you have that

$$\sum_{k = n+1}^m {1\over k^2}\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^m \left[\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right]$$ This is a telescoping series which is equal to $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$. It converges to zero as $n,m\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Now, use the fact that$$\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac1{k^2}<\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac1k-\frac1{k-1}=\frac1n-\frac1m.$$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like I went into paralysis by analysis trying to over-express the sum I had. Thanks!

Comment: Why do we need the hint?
Can't we simply say that as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent, we know that that $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ which shows the claim, too.

Comment: In order to prove that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, $\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac1{k^2}<\varepsilon$, if $m$ and $n$ are large enough.

Comment: @JonasLenz I guess that is how one shows that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ convergent.

Comment: Okay, if one can not use this, is totally agree.
In general one can replace $\frac{1}{k^2}$ be any summable sequence and the result is still true.